# Page Displays Different In Debug Than In Design View

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

If I display my page in design view it looks exactly like I want it to, but when I debug the page does not display as it should.  The grid will extend past the bottom of the page.  What do I need to do to make my "design" view of my page look just like my "debug" view of my page?

Here is my site.master syntax that works great on all but 3 pages (I have over 200 in my project).

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sptScriptManager" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div>
                <table class="Color3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                <!--Table showing all the menu information-->
                </table>
                <div class="White" style="height: 14px;"></div>
                <div class="main" id="divMain">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div class="Color1" style="height: 40px; margin-top:50px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Color2" style="height: 300px;">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblhaeia" CssClass="CustomBold"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is on the page how I am calling it.  In design view everything looks as it should, but If I run this page in debug the grid spans down past the bottom of the `</asp:Content>` tag

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="asd" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="true" Visible="false" OnItemDataBound="asd_OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemStyle CssClass="row" /><FooterStyle CssClass="DataGridFooters" /><HeaderStyle CssClass="DataGridHeaders" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="123" HeaderText="123" ItemStyle-Width="137px">
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="erf" HeaderText="erf"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="mmm" HeaderText="mmm"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="acxz" HeaderText="axcz" DataFormatString="{0:N}"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="qaz" HeaderText="qaz"
                DataFormatString="{0:N}" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            </asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="b" HeaderText="b" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="tt" HeaderText="tt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="nnne" HeaderText="nnne" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="flam" HeaderText="flam"
                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>  
</asp:Content>
```

And finally the CSS that may or may not be skewing this stuff

```
.Color1
{
    background-color: #689e1c; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 55px;
}
.Color2
{
    background-color: #333881;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 20px; 
    display: block;
}
.Color3
{
    background-color: #001199; 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.CustomBold
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
.White
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
}
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: auto; 
}
.body   
{
    background: #b6b7bc;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #696969;
}
```

Comment: can you add scrollbars to your grid?

Comment: main in your css should be .main

Comment: What's wrong with that? If your data grid contains many records like 100 or more then html for the datagrid will automatically expand vertically and horizontally to render its contents. `This is normal and expected behavior`.  Now `in design view` you are not binding the data grid so it has no records and therefore it displays according to what you want.

Comment: You cannot compare `design view` with `rendered view in browser` since in design view there is no data being used to populate the server controls.

Comment: @Sunil - but I have the ContentPlaceHolder set so that all data that the page renders will display inside what the ContentPlaceHolder is set to show.  I thought that was the purpose of using such?

Comment: @Lola - type, both main and white should be .main and .white - the issue is not the grid goes to far down on the page, the issue is that the grid spans outside of the contentplaceholder.  I need all data that the page renders to be inside the contentplaceholder.

Comment: if you can add overflow: scroll; to the main css element you should get a scrollbar on your content allowing it to stay on one page

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight, Even the ContentPlaceHolder will expand itself to accomodate and render its contents. That is normal html behavior. `By default html is like fluid`, so it automatically expands to show its contents, UNLESS you restrict the html element to have a certain width and height.

Comment: @Lola - this still causes the grid to expand beyond the placeholder but it now places the gridview results on top of the placeholder as opposed to under it.

Comment: @Sunil - no where on the page is an html element set to alter height.  Again this syntax works on all other pages in my project.

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight, I meant that if you set height then only html will try to not expand. Html does not need anything to alter its height so the answer to your question in last comment is `nothing`. It will act fluid by itself without you doing anything.

Comment: @Sunil - then what is preventing the grid from expanding within the contentplaceholder?

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight, The grid is expanding because you mentioned that in some pages its extending down.

Comment: @Sunil - the grid is expanding yes.  But I want it to expand within the bounds of the contentplaceholder.  I want the contentplaceholder to be the top and bottom of the page, and have NOTHING outside the bounds of it.  Why is the grid expanding past the contentplaceholder?

Comment: @RedLightGreenLight,,  Your situation seems not very straightforward, so I would suggest you to post the html of rendered page in browser. You can  right click on page in browser and select View Source to open the rendered html. Copy and paste it under this post.